# Power El wire from Mains

Tags: frequency, inverter, el-wire

I have been looking at EL wire inverter, and most are battery powered.
I want to power it from mains power.

I was looking at having a transformer to step down from 220AC to 110AC.
This gives me 110AC at 60Hz.
Good voltage for most El wire but too low frequency.
So now...i would like help to get a higher frequency...

Anyone has a simple idea?

Or even a different approach?

Comment: Figuring out how to increase your frequency would be unnecessarily complicated. You can use a wall wart rated for the inverter and power the EL wire from it.

Comment: The following site has some interesting information on how to power EL wire using battery and mains power: https://learn.adafruit.com/el-wire/using-el-wire

Answer (score 1):

To change frequency you basically have to convert to DC and back to AC.

It would certainly be possible to build a circuit to do this at 110V but the cost of high voltage power electronics would almost certainly make it uneconomical given the low power requirements of EL wire.

By far the easiest approach to powering EL wire off the mains will be to get an off the shelf EL inverter and an off the shelf DC power supply and wire them together.